# Do JBehave scenarios get run in order within a story file?

Tags: java, jbehave

I know we can configure stories to run within a specific order and require specific scenarios to have run for dependent stories but do JBehave scenarios get run in order within a single story file, even in multi-threaded context?

Comment: It would be great if whoever down voted could provide some meaningful comment...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the one who down-voted your question, Russell, but I'll explain.  JBehave will run in the order in which they are listed in the story files.  Just the same, it's best to code your scenarios as if you could not rely on the scenarios to run in sequence.  Each Scenario should be able to function on its own.  This order, in my opinion, is a huge advantage for BDD over simply using JUnit or TestNG alone.

Comment: Thanks very much. I appreciate that ideally the scenarios should be independent but I'm testing a series of business processes implemented through a process engine which results in the current state depending on previous state, hence for each scenario to be independent would make it hundreds of not thousands of steps long

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Given Stories](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/given-stories.html)?  These allow you to specify a story or scenario that should be run before executing the current story or scenario.  I think the usual example for this is a story that tests a checkout functionality should first execute the story which adds an item to the cart. These would then be executed in specific order.

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it would have the effect of forcing an order of execution between scenarios.